# Maven commands produce no output on the command line

Tags: java, maven

When I try to run commands like mvn -v or mvn -help there is no output and just adds a new line. No errors or anything, just blank. My maven and java work fine because I can still build and run code in my ide, but nothing shows up on the command line. I have not changed my path or environment variables, it just stopped working overnight.

[image][image]

Comment: That looks there is a big issue...because neither `java -version` does not output anything at all... also for `mvn --version`...`mvn clean build` (`build` does not exist!)...

Comment: @khmarbaise any ideas? I've never run into something like this before